# How is the Trend measure being calculated in the Power BI Usage Metrics reports?

Tags: powerbi, dax

The link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-modern-usage-metrics says "The view trend reflects view count changes over time. It compares the first half of the selected time period with the second half." but how would I do this with a measure?

Answer (score 0):

View Trend measure is available in the dataset in modern workspace usage metric.  However it is not available in the classic workspace usage metric or the old usage metrics report.  This DAX is what I have written and have been using...

```
 Trend = 
    VAR StartDate = MIN(Views[Date])
    VAR EndDate = MAX(Views[Date])
    VAR PeriodHalfDaysCount = INT((MAX(Views[Date])-MIN(Views[Date]))/2)
    VAR MidDate = StartDate+PeriodHalfDaysCount
    
    VAR FirstHalfView = CALCULATE([ViewsCount], DATESBETWEEN(Views[Date],StartDate,MidDate))
    VAR SecondHalfView = CALCULATE([ViewsCount], `enter code here`DATESBETWEEN(Views[Date],MidDate+1,Enddate))
    
    RETURN DIVIDE (SecondHalfView-FirstHalfView,FirstHalfView)
```